# getting file and directories count using scala

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to get the count of files and directories in my `D:/work` folder using scala partition method, but I'm getting error

```
import java.io._

val fd = (new File("D:/work/")).listFiles

scala> fd.partition ( x => {case x.isFile() => "FILE"; case x.isDirectory() => "DIR" } )

<console>:28: error: missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: Boolean
       fd.partition ( x => {case x.isFile() => "FILE"; case x.isDirectory() => "DIR" } )
                           ^
<console>:28: error: method isFile is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
       fd.partition ( x => {case x.isFile() => "FILE"; case x.isDirectory() => "DIR" } )
                             ^
<console>:28: error: method isDirectory is not a case class, nor does it have an unapply/unapplySeq member
       fd.partition ( x => {case x.isFile() => "FILE"; case x.isDirectory() => "DIR" } )
                                                              ^

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with your code, indicating, that you should, probably, start with reading a book on scala syntax (that's why you are getting the down-votes).

It seems pointless at this point to enumerate everything that's wrong with your snippet. Something like this would do what you want:

```
  val (files, directories) = fd.partition(_.isFile)
```

Or something like this if you are looking to get a map rather than a tuple:

```
  val filesDirs = fd.groupBy { 
     case x if x.isFile => "FILE"
     case _ => "DIR"
  }
```